# Android layout - distinguish different screen height on same DPI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, dpi

I testing my app on a different emulators provided by the Android Studio. I've created a multiple drawable and values folders to match the various DPIs.
My problem is when testing 2 different screens sizes, both detected as LDPI in runtime.

240x432 120DPI, 240x320 120DPI.

My layout has 4 buttons and 1 image with vertical orientation (one below the other). The layout fits the 432 height, but it's cut on the 320 height. If I make it to match the 320 height, the layout fills about 75% of the height and does not provide the best user experience. The problems is obvious here: What fits 432 can not fit 320.

What would be the best practice handling such situation? I want to avoid "stretching" the layout in runtime by factoring the height. Is there a compile time Android Studio solution creating the exact height layout.?

I am targeting min SDK 15.

Comment: How about using scroll view? Or if you do not want to use scroll view how about using PercentReleativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
   android:height="match_parent"

Comment: I am using it already. The issue is that the main layout contains 5 buttons and the image. On 320 resolutions, the buttons are going out of the screen.

Comment: could you please post your xml

Comment: It is a long one. Let me try to simplify. If I have a Layout with android:height="match_parent", this would fit the screen's height. But this would not affect the height of this buttons if they have a fixed dp, right?

Comment: you should use weight for child elements , specify the hieght of the linear layout as match parent and weight of each button as 1 or as required